# Java/Android: OnClickListener + Camera preview = bad performance?

Tags: java, android

I ran in troubles during developing an Augmented-Reality application.

In this application the user sees the camera preview with some location-based overlay views pointing to the direction where the locations are. He must turn around his own axis to see what is around him.

The camera view itself is a SurfaceView where the preview is rendered to. The structure of the views is following:

```
RelativeLayout
-- SurvaceView (the camera preview)
-- RelativeLayout 1 (one of these floating views containing some labels)
-- RelativeLayout 2 (another floating view pointing to another location)
```

The floating views are moved by translationX and translationY and follows the compass bearing. These position updates happens up to 20x per second and are butterly smooth.

It works fine so far. But these floating views must be clickable so I set an OnClickListener to each of them.

That turns the smoothy thing into a very very jerky and ugly one.

Where this performance hit comes from? Any idea or solution?

(Sorry, I can't show the source to you)

Tanks :-)

Comment: OnClickListener  on what ?

Comment: on the floating views